# Getting data to show on another sheet using dropdown list as a referance

Tags: microsoft-excel

What I have is a sheet called home, that has a drop down list, what I wish to do is depending on what displays in the drop down this would then populate other cells on the home sheet with data from another sheet called data.

At present this drop down list also pulls in a picture from another sheet called Pictures. This uses the VLOOKUP function. Data sheet column A, duplicates what is in the drop down list on the home sheet, @ W7

Data sheet column B to row 9 has part of my data to return to home sheet. this data starts at column J1, row 13 and would populate down to row J22.
 Data sheet column C to row 9 has the rest of my data to return to home sheet. this data starts at Column Q16 and would populate down to row Q25.

At the moment I am using VLOOKUP on a text box to do this but this is not acceptable as all the data is distorted at times.

Comment: If you consider the answer below to be suitable, then please click the gray tick beside it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, general description:

Make the dropdown list either contain or somehow allow to generate the TOP LEFT cell of the data range you want to display.

Then use INDIRECT(...) and OFFSET(...) on a character string (forming a cell reference), generated with the TOP LEFT cell above. By that you fill in a table - which is to hold what you have selected in the dropdown list.

Tip: ROWS(range) and COLUMNS(range) can be used to create offsets for OFFSET(...), assuming you use e.g. "$A$1:A1" as range (first cell ref locked, the second not).

Comment: Ok I'm fairly new to using vlookup etc so real I have no idea when you say top left

Comment: No VLOOKUP() here. "Top left" is top left corner cell of (each of) the Excel ranges you're interested in.